# Efficient algorithm for MEM finding

Tags: string, algorithm, search, pattern-matching

MEM is the abbreviation of "Maximum Exact Matching" problem, and the aim in this problem is finding all maximum similar substring between two input string. Please take note this problem is a little bit different from string matching problem (or text search) wich you want to find a given string in another text.

For example in two following strings (with finite charcharchers { 1,2,3}) MEM's are "12" and "3312"

str1:"12233312"

str2:"123312"

For exmaple 233 is also common substring between two input strings, but since there is another biger substring which include it, we don't consider it as a MEM.

Does anyone has some elegant idea how to solve it. A very trivial idea can be using search algorithm for finding all possible substring of smaller string in big string with some fast string search algorithm like Boyer–Moore . But it doesn't seem to be an efficient way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Isnt this just the Longest Common Substring 'problem'? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: I am not looking only for one common maximum substring, but also for all possible common maximum substring. but maybe I would be able to use the idea

Comment: 233 is *not* included in a bigger common substring.

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear-time algorithm.

1. Build a suffix tree on `str1 + "X" + str2`, where `'X'` does not appear in `str1` or `str2`.
2. Some of the leaf nodes correspond to suffixes that begin in `str1` (contain `'X'`). Color these red. Color the others blue.
3. Walk the tree root-to-leaves to label each node with the length of the string to it from the root.
4. Walk the tree leaves-to-root to find the leaf-most nodes that have both a red descendant and a blue descendant. The label computed in Step 3 is the length of the common substring.

Answer (score 1):

I found the paper which I was looking for this problem. The idea is simiallr to one David Eisenstat mentioined. Actually I don't need to concatinate two strings and ..., I can build the suffix tree of the first string and then the suffix tree of the second string on previos tree. what it means is when I am traversing the previous tree to find a way for the secons string, I can find common path whcih shows common substring.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23349213

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that relatively easy, its called dynamic programming. 
[image]
Create a boolean 2D table, your first dimension is your str1, your second dimension is str2. Set to true all your common numbers. Once you complete your bollean 2D table, iterate diagonally and find the max count of true.

Comment: time complexity and memory usage of this program is o(n^2) I need some more efficient algorithm. especially because in my case one string is too long (suppose 1000000 character) and another one is smaller.then this table is so sparse and waist of memory. If i decide to implement it with link list idea then time complexity should be another issue. but up to now it was the best idea thanks.

Comment: Firstly. I didn't write neither presented any 'program'. I just showed you how you can potentially solve your problem. Secondly, specify all your requirements *first* in detail before you start adding them after someone has replied to you. Lastly, I suggest you to read how dynamic programming works. Its *your* program that will make the difference about efficiency